# Excel macro shortcut-key with forms

Tags: excel-2010

I have a couple of Excel macros that I run with keyboard shortcuts. All is well unless the focus is on a form when the shortcut key simply does not do anything. If I set focus away from the form the shortcut key works again. It doesn't seem to matter if the form is loaded modeless or not. Is there a way around this?

Thanks in advance.